# Download remote files wirh ftp-simple on vs code

Tags: visual-studio, ftp

I've installed ftp-simple on vs-code (I can connect with FileZilla) and
I pressed <kbd>F1</kbd>, typed config:

```
[
    {
        "name": "dev-server",
        "host": "192.168.0.140",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "user",
        "password": "12345",
        "path": "/var/www/WebApp",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }
]
```

Pressed <kbd>F1</kbd> again, remote directory open to workspace..and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed it does take quite a while, you have to be patient, it will load the remote structure eventually. Once loaded, then save as a Workspace.